# Where can I do a long retreat?

Tags: retreat

Could different people here recommend places I can do long retreats (in 2 months for example)?

I wanted to do a retreat in the style of meditation I do right now: Mahasi Sayadaw following Ven. Ajhan Tong sirimangalo technique -- where you do mindful prostrations, then walking and sitting while using labeling.

But they only agree for 10 days, and at the end of 10 days they tell you whether you can stay for another 10 days.

So I'm looking for a place to go do a long retreat, of say 2 months -- it can be in different technique even  (say even only metta for example) , that isn't close to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [Kanduboda Meditation Center](http://www.insight-meditation.org/) which teachers Mahasi Meditation. You have to inquire before hand about the length of your stay.

Also you can try [Mitirigala Nissarana Vanaya](http://www.nissarana.lk/). Again double check the particular days. This teachers both Mahasi and Pa Auk methods under [Most Venerable UdaEriyagama Dhammajiva Maha Thero](http://www.nissarana.lk/most-venerable-udaeriyagama-dhammajiva-maha-thero/)

Also there are centres in Sri Lanka, Burma, Thai Land and Malaysia which you can try.

Also see: [Meditation Centres in Sri Lanka](http://www.vipassana.com/resources/meditation_in_sri_lanka.php) by Andrew Quernmore

Also you might try to use [World Buddhist Directory](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/).

Also Goenka Centres does have long retreats if you fulfill some conditions:

> 10-day Courses for Old Students have the same timetable and discipline as 10-day courses. These courses are open to serious old students who have completed at least three 10-day courses and one Satipaṭṭhāna Sutta course, have not been practising any other meditation techniques since last 10-day course, have been practising this technique of Vipassana for at least one year, are trying to maintain the five precepts in their daily lives, and trying to maintain daily practice.
>
> Special 10-day Courses are open only to serious Old Students committed to this technique who have completed a minimum of five 10-day courses, one Satipatthana Sutta course, given Dhamma Service at least one 10-day course, and have been practicing regularly for at least two years.
>
> Applications must be submitted well in advance as processing may take some time. Students who speak neither English nor one of the other announced course languages may apply for the course, however acceptance into the course will depend on the availability of required course materials, suitable translators and permission of the teacher conducting the course.
>
> 20-day Courses are open only to serious Old Students committed to this technique who have completed a minimum of five 10-day courses , one Satipatthana Sutta course, given Dhamma Service at least one 10-day course, and have been practicing regularly for at least two years.
>
> Applications must be submitted well in advance as processing may take some time. Students who speak neither English nor one of the other announced course languages may apply for the course, however acceptance into the course will depend on the availability of required course materials, suitable translators and permission of the teacher conducting the course.
>
> 30-day Courses are open only to serious Old Students committed to this technique who have completed a minimum of six 10-day courses (one since their first 20-day course), one 20-day course, one Satipatthana Sutta course, and have been practicing regularly for at least two years.
>
> Applications must be submitted well in advance as processing may take some time. Students who speak neither English nor one of the other announced course languages may apply for the course, however acceptance into the course will depend on the availability of required course materials, suitable translators and permission of the teacher conducting the course.
>
> 45-day Courses are open only to persons involved in Dhamma Service and Assistant Teachers who have completed a minimum of seven 10-day courses (one since their first 30-day course), two 30-day courses, one Satipatthana Sutta course, and have been practicing regularly for at least three years.
>
> Applications must be submitted well in advance as processing may take some time. Students who speak neither English nor one of the other announced course languages may apply for the course, however acceptance into the course will depend on the availability of required course materials, suitable translators and permission of the teacher conducting the course.
>
> 60-day Courses are open only to active Teachers and Assistant teachers who have completed two 45 Day courses and conduct at least 4 courses annually.
>
> Applications must be submitted well in advance as processing may take some time. Students who speak neither English nor one of the other announced course languages may apply for the course, however acceptance into the course will depend on the availability of required course materials, suitable translators and permission of the teacher conducting the course.
>
> Satipatthana Sutta Courses have the same timetable and discipline as 10-day courses. The difference is that in the taped evening discourses the Satipatthana Sutta is carefully examined. This is the principal text in which the technique of Vipassana is systematically explained. These courses are open to serious old students who have sat (not including courses served) at least three 10-day courses, have not been practising any other meditation techniques since last 10-day course, have been practising this technique of Vipassana for at least one year, and who are trying to maintain their meditation practice and the five precepts in their daily lives, at the very minimum from the time of applying to the course.
>
> Old Student Short Courses (1-3 days) are for any student who has completed the 10-day course with S.N. Goenka and his assistant teachers. All old students are welcome to apply to attend these courses, including those where it has been some time since their last course.

Source: https://www.dhamma.org/en/schedules/schtapovana

Answer (score 3):

http://www.watmetta.org/
Ajan Geoff is the teacher he. He is very knowledge about Buddhism in general, however is trained as a monk of the Thai Forest Tradition.

Comment: its a hassle to contact the though  -  only by phone or mail (actual mail not email)

Comment: ha yeah tell me about it. usually you can get through if you call between 5 and 6 and they are actually pretty good about calling back.

Comment: i live in israel - so it will be an out of state call which is problematic to do  - but thanks for the comment it makes me think of all options  -  really the more options the better - so thanks

Comment: I do like ajan Geoff though - read some books of his  - maybe there is another place that has the same teachings i can stay at ?

Answer (score 3):

The list given by Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena is quite exhaustive. 
I will just add that if you never did a long retreat before, you should probably first start by a 10 days retreat.

I already did small retreat of 3 days of zazen in Japan, but I found the 10 days retreat of Goenka to be really hard and just couldn't imagine doing it for 20 days while I was there, it's a big jump. I will certainly do a few more 10 days retreat and will look forward doing 20 days in a row when I will feel ready.

Short answer: It is up to you, but I really suggest you test yourself on 10 days (goenka or not) if you have no prior experience. Because if you were to fail during a longer retreat you will face the risk to be disgusted by meditation or blame yourself while you just gave yourself a too big of challenge.

Comment: I did 16 days intense retreat at meditation center also 10 days retreat at home (which is harder)   

Im aware of how hard its going to be

Comment: Wow great ! in that case I think you won't be able to apply to Goenka unless you first do the ten days first, but depending on their schedule you can maybe achieve to do it in a consecutive manner: applying to a 10 days course, followed right after by a 20 days course etc.  I heard they do longer period then 20 days (like one or two months) once in a while. Probably India is the best bet.

Answer (score 3):

These courses are the best imo, held in Hamilton, ON Canada, on an individual, on-going basis, free of charge, including room and board for the duration of the course dependent on keeping the eight Buddhist precepts for meditators

**Foundation Course – 21 days (approx.)**

...Foundation Course in Satipatthana Vipassana Meditation as their first course.  Meditation techniques include mindful prostration, one- to six-step walking meditation, sitting meditation based on the rising and falling of the abdomen, the sitting posture, points of bodily contact, as well as contemplation of daily activities from morning to night.

The emphasis in this course is on learning the basic technique of recognition (sati – a.k.a. mindfulness) of the body, feelings, mind, and dhammas (meditation objects) in the present moment.  **The course follows, as its technical outline, the sixteen stages of insight knowledge found in primary Buddhist texts and commentaries;** no formal instruction in the stages of knowledge, however, is given in the foundation course and not all meditators will obtain the same results from the course.

Course content includes daily interviews with a teacher and regular group lectures. No previous experience is required, but advanced meditators in other meditation techniques may request a streamlined course to suit their needs.

They also offer advandanced courses to people who have completed the foundation course or the online course, so one could theoretically streamline several courses https://www.sirimangalo.org/courses/#med

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any comment on the possibility of a 2-month-long retreat?

Comment: It is possible to stay for longer time if the Abbot allows it, however i would not expect an open invitation to stay for 2 months, one could probably ask to be allowed to stay if one was to complete the Foundation Course. I know of people who stayed for several months.

Comment: checked and its only available from august

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Tisarana Buddhist Monastery in Perth, Ontario](https://tisarana.ca/), for you. It is near Ottawa – the Capital City of Canada. I was there just one month ago. You can [take a look into their FB Page too,](https://www.facebook.com/pg/TBBKK/photos/?tab=album&album_id=358216725068) if you like - as it will give you a better idea.

The monastery is a residence for Buddhist monks and those who wish to train as Buddhist monks. Presently there are 20 monks, and 4 'anagaarika's (trainee monks). It is also a retreat for those  interested who may visit for varying periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

Ven. Ajahn Tong Sirimangalo lives at Wat Chomtong. The foundation course is 21 days. That could be a nice start. There are more monasteries with similar style that do 21 day foundation courses like Wat Doi Suthep and Wat Rampoeng. 
It's possible to stay much longer at Mahasi Sasana Yeiktha Meditation Centre Yangon. I can't find the folder they gave me though, so I don't know the exact conditions.

Comment: Thanks  -  i went first to panditarama  center in myanmar for 2 months (i think they even accept 3 months there)   -  but they spoke 0 English ! i left after 2 days  went to thailand dissapointed  - but than did  20 days in chom tong  - where they speak excellent English  

.... after a few days traveling went back for another ten days but it was too much for me so left after a day lol

Comment: It's good to understand the instructions, that's also why I prefer Wat Chom Tong.

Comment: After the foundation course I really had to recover! Amazing that you went back so soon. Last year I informed if it's possible to do longer stays. It's possible, but it's going to be the standard 10 day review course, take some time off, then do another 10 day review course.